# How to solve the problem incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[64]' to parameter of type 'const char **'

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, qsort

I kept getting `incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[64]' to parameter of type 'const char **'` when I pass the `name[100][64]` in the `sort` function and end up getting `segmentation fault 11`

```
#define size 100
#define type 10
// Defining comparator function as per the requirement
static int myCompare(const void* a, const void* b){
    return strcmp(*(const char**)a, *(const char**)b);
}
void sort(int n, const char* arr){
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(const char*), myCompare);
}
int main(){
    int num; scanf("%d", &num);
    char name[100][64];
    //input
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        scanf("%s", name[i]);
    }
    //sort
    sort(num, &name[0]);
}
```

I have tried `char* name[100];` to solve the problem, but still get the warning - `segmentation fault 11`

```
char* name[100];
//input
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
   scanf("%s", name[i]);
}
sort(num, name);
```

I want to know how to input several strings and sort them like a dictionary.

Comment: The size of each element for `qsort` isn't `sizeof(const char*)` but `64`, the inner array dimension.

Comment: And then the comparator shoud be `return strcmp((const char*)a, (const char*)b);`. Or simpler: `qsort(arr, n, 64, strcmp);`

Comment: Regarding the second snippet. `char* name[100];` allocates 100 uninitialized pointers that don't point to memory you can use to store data. `scanf("%s", name[i]);` tries to read data into where they point which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Hmm, at least 4 bugs ... GTG

Comment: From `main` just call `qsort(name, num, sizeof name[0], strcmp);`. All the other complication can go.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you totally. Your advices are very helpful. It perfectly sorts the inputs. However, I still get the warning: incompatible function pointer types passing 'int (const char *, const char *)' to parameter of type 'int (* _Nonnull)(const void *, const void *)' [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
    qsort(name, num, 64, strcmp); I'm just curious why and how.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you. I should have allocated the memory before scanf.

Comment: Even with -Wall I'm not getting any warning from MSVC about that but you could try `qsort(&name[0], num, sizeof name[0], strcmp);`. Or is it warning about passing `int` to `size_t`? But *"to parameter of type `int`"* – `qsort` doesn't have any `int` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a character array like

```
char name[100][64];
```

used in expressions like a function argument it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char ( * )[64]`.

Or if to use this call

```
sort(num, &name[0]);
```

then again the expression `&name[0]` that is equivalent to the expression `name` used as an argument has the type `char ( * )[64]`

However the function `sort` where the array is used as an argument has type of the corresponding parameter `const char **`.

```
void sort(int n, const char* arr){
```

There is no implicit conversion between the pointer types. And moreover if even to use an explicit casting nevertheless the call will be incorrect because the argument will mean that you are passing an array of pointers. But the function `qsort` will need to swap elements of the type `char[64]` instead of elements of the type `const char *`.

Your functions can look the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define size 100
#define type 10

static int myCompare( const void *a, const void *b ) {
    return strcmp( *( const char ( * )[type] )a, *( const char ( * )[type] )b );
}
void sort( char ( *arr )[type], size_t n  ) {
    qsort( arr, n, sizeof( *arr ), myCompare );
}

int main( void )
{
    char name[size][type] =
    {
        "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0"
    };

    size_t num = 10;

    sort( name, num );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf( "%s ", name[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Nicely done without any unnecessary casts nor naked magic numbers.